# How do I include subfolders, and how do I have .h files inside subfolders find other .h files in other subfolders?

Tags: ros, include, catkin, headers, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may be best to look at this example: https://github.com/PR2/linux_networking/tree/hydro-devel/wpa_supplicant_node

I'm trying to get the code here to compile but it can't find

"/home/marco/pr2_hydro_packages/src/linux_networking/wpa_supplicant_node/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_i.h:18:24: fatal error: utils/list.h: No such file or directory."

My question is, how do I set up the CMakeLists in catkin so that the wpa_supplicant_i.h can find the utils/list.h file which exists in another subdirectory? I've tried including all of the paths, and no avail.

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194064/how-do-i-include-subfolders,-and-how-do-i-have-.h-files-inside-subfolders-find-other-.h-files-in-other-subfolders?/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it seems you've tried a lot of things, and that is confusing the issue. As far I can see, none of the things in this line are going to work:

https://github.com/PR2/linux_networking/blob/hydro-devel/wpa_supplicant_node/CMakeLists.txt#L16

It appears there is a copy of `wpa_supplicant` in both the `wpa_supplicant` package and the `wpa_supplicant_node` package. I'm not sure which one you want to do, but is there a reason you don't just install `wpa_supplicant` from apt-get?

This is one of the root issues, from where do you want to get `utils/list.h`?

If `utils/list.h` is to be provided from `wpa_supplicant_node`, then you just need something like this in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `wpa_supplicant_node`:

```
include_directories(wpa_supplicant/src)
```

Because in that case `utils/list.h` is in `<git root>/wpa_supplicant_node/wpa_supplicant/src/utils/list.h`. You were close, you had this in the above linked line: `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}wpa_supplicant/src`, but the missing space between `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `wpa_supplicant/src` causes them to be concatenated, so that will not work. I think if you put a space between those two and remove all the other entries it should work.

If `utils/list.h` is provided by another package (like `wpa_supplicant`) then you'll need to do something like what is suggested here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/93266/how-to-export-non-standard-include-directories-in-catkin/?answer=93281#post-id-93281

Basically you need to install the header add the folder which contains `utils/list.h` to your exported include paths for the `wpa_supplicant` package.

If `wpa_supplicant` is to be used from the system (installed using apt-get) then your `pkg-config` approach in `wpa_supplicant_node`, which is currently commented out, might work. You'd have to look at `wpa_supplicant`'s upstream documentation to find out how you are supposed to build against it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-10-02**:
Thanks! This worked.